# Authentication with Stripe Subscriptions Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jwt, stripe-payments

I am having trouble determining the best method to attack subscription auth with Stripe. I have a pre-existing MERN stack that is using JWT's for authentication, storing the subscription id. However, to detect changes such as cancellations, incomplete invoices, etc, I can't think of a solution without sockets.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Before you renew a JWT, just check the status of the Subscription - and make sure the expiry is short enough to make you comfortable in terms of unpaid access window.

You could also have some middleware that does this for every ajax request (or at least a common/frequent ajax request) as well, that returns a 402 and invalidates the JWT if the subscription is no longer considered 'paid'.

Comment: Yeah, so my thought was reloading the User Schema for example, every 5 minutes (from the JWT expiry) and comparing status there for disputes if valid, sending along a refreshed user object. Or keeping general auth and subscriptions in separated or embedded tokens. My only concern with having such short expiry on the general auth token is validating a refresh of the token

Comment: @NicholasDullam This might be a useful article for you: https://auth0.com/blog/blacklist-json-web-token-api-keys/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at stripe webhooks for receiving event notifications.

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Listen for events on your Stripe account so your integration can automatically trigger reactions.

Stripe uses webhooks to notify your application when an event happens in your account. Webhooks are particularly useful for asynchronous events like when a customer’s bank confirms a payment, a customer disputes a charge, or a recurring payment succeeds.

Begin using webhooks with your Stripe integration in just three steps:

1.Create a webhook endpoint on your server.

2.Use the Stripe CLI to test that your endpoint works.

3.Register the endpoint with Stripe to go live.

Basic example of creating webhook

```
// This example uses Express to receive webhooks
const app = require('express')();

// Use body-parser to retrieve the raw body as a buffer
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Match the raw body to content type application/json
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  let event;

  try {
    event = JSON.parse(request.body);
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
      // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
      break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
      const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
      // handlePaymentMethodAttached(paymentMethod);
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      return response.status(400).end();
  }

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.json({received: true});
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Running on port 8000'));
```

Comment: Yeah, I was planning on utilizing web hooks as far as database changes were concerned. I am more so leaning towards the refreshing of credentials client side without the use of web sockets if that makes sense. Appreciate your response